# How to tell when the Operating System was installed?

Tags: installation, boot, system, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date Ubuntu was installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/date-ubuntu-was-installed)

`uptime` shows how long ago the computer was started, and that is very handy to know, but I want to know how long ago the system was installed.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/date-ubuntu-was-installed

Answer (score 0):

I would check the creation date of the /boot folder.

Comment: I checked in my computer, and this folder is dated yesterday (which is obviously wrong).