# how to retrieve server life uptime?

Tags: 18.04, server, uptime

Is there a command or script that can tell me for how long the server has been up since installation?
(either by checking system installation date (+ removing shutdown-time) or by checking main disk uptime)

something similar to what "crystal disk info" can do for windows

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what date Ubuntu was installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/how-can-i-tell-what-date-ubuntu-was-installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe we have something like that.

This will show when a system was installed:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem created:'
Filesystem created:       Sat Jun 14 18:29:43 2014
```

Replace /dev/sda1 with the device name you need (1st column of `df /` will show you what you want). But I do not believe I ever saw a command to show how long a system has been turned on or off.

```
uptime
```

will only show how long the current uptime is.

This will list the last 1000 reboots/shutdowns:

```
last -1000 reboot shutdown
```

But that lacks the moment the system was turned on after a shutdown.

edit:

How about an approach like this (it will list the hours a disk has been active):

```
 smartctl --attributes /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours
```

Replace `/dev/sda` with your device name and install it with `sudo apt smartmontools` if not available yet. Not totally perfect as it assumes you started using the disk when the system was installed.

Comment: It gives me the error (translated): "tune2fs: magic value not correct in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1" what could be the problem?

Comment: (I will leave the answer open for few days so if someone has some other idea can write it here)

Comment: @gekigek99 use sudo and make sure your partition is /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

I you had already installed the `downtimed` daemon (`apt install downtimed`) to your system during installation, you could have obtained that information as shown in the following example:

```
$ downtimes
down  2020-07-12 16:25:15 -> up 2020-07-12 16:25:54 =    00:00:39 (39 s)
down  2020-07-19 22:23:17 -> up 2020-07-19 22:23:57 =    00:00:40 (40 s)
down  2020-07-22 21:38:07 -> up 2020-07-22 21:38:47 =    00:00:40 (40 s)
down  2020-07-29 19:35:47 -> up 2020-07-29 19:36:28 =    00:00:41 (41 s)
down  2020-09-01 12:11:55 -> up 2020-09-01 12:12:36 =    00:00:41 (41 s)
down  2020-09-03 10:08:59 -> up 2020-09-03 10:09:40 =    00:00:41 (41 s)
down  2020-09-03 10:13:16 -> up 2020-09-03 10:15:25 =    00:02:09 (129 s)
down  2020-09-08 18:24:28 -> up 2020-09-08 18:25:07 =    00:00:39 (39 s)
down  2020-09-22 18:06:52 -> up 2020-09-22 18:07:31 =    00:00:39 (39 s)
```

But, the current version of `downtimes` command does not display the cumulative time; you have to calculate yourself.

---

Another option is the `last` command (as long as the `/var/log/wtmp` file is not "rotated"). See the following example:

```
$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1025-aws   Tue Sep 22 18:07   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1024-aws   Tue Sep  8 18:25 - 18:06 (13+23:41)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1022-aws   Thu Sep  3 10:15 - 18:24 (5+08:09)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1022-aws   Thu Sep  3 10:09 - 10:13  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1022-aws   Tue Sep  1 12:12 - 10:09 (1+21:56)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1021-aws   Wed Jul 29 19:36 - 12:11 (33+16:35)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1020-aws   Wed Jul 22 21:38 - 19:35 (6+21:57)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1018-aws   Sun Jul 19 22:23 - 21:38 (2+23:14)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1018-aws   Sun Jul 12 16:25 - 22:23 (7+05:57)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1018-aws   Sun Jul 12 15:22 - 16:25  (01:02)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1015-aws   Sun Jul 12 14:01 - 15:21  (01:20)
```

The shows the system's "uptimes". But, again you have to sum them up yourself.